# My question is about Either or/Neither nor

Tags: conjunctions, neither-nor

> I am  not watching the movie on TV. I am not watching the movie on my laptop.

Should I use either-or or neither-nor?

Comment: *I'm not watching the movie on TV nor on my laptop.*

Comment: Both can be used. Just remember to keep the word 'not' while using either-or and omit the word 'not' if you use neither-nor

Answer (score 1):

You can use both.

> I am not watching the movie on TV. I am not watching the movie on my laptop either.

"Either" is used in the same meaning as "too" in the negative statements.

> I am watching the movie neither on TV nor on my laptop.

This is used to unite two negative ideas.You can also use

> I am not watching the movie on TV or on my laptop

For emphasis you can use "nor" after a pause.

> I am not watching the movie on TV, nor on my laptop.

Comment: The OP wasn't asking about using _'either'_ alone. He was very specific about using _'either-or'_. The rest is fine though.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, as Monica Sendi Afa said, you need to *keep the 'not'* in the sentence when using 'either-or', but you need to *remove the 'not'* from the sentence when using 'neither-nor'. Having said that,

In the case of using 'either-or', your example sentence will be

> "I am ***not*** watching the movie ***either*** on TV ***or*** on my
>   laptop."

In the case of using 'neither-nor", your example sentence will be

> "I am watching the movie ***neither*** on TV ***nor*** on my laptop."